# Should a footnote (superscript number) directly follow the word?

Tags: typography, typesetting, white-space

I have footnotes in my manuscript. Each footnote is indicated by a number in superscript. Should the number directly (without a space) follow the word? Or should a space be placed between the word and the footnote number in superscript?

Comment: Usually I've seen no space.

Comment: Definitely no space. And it should come _after_ any punctuation, not before it (except an end parenthesis if the footnote pertains specifically to the text inside the parentheses).

Comment: Is there any reference for this? I will happily accept an answer to my question if somebody willing to write one. It seems like common sense to not put a space before any punctuation, so this should also hold for footnote superscript numbers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, It can depend on how the note system is used. If the note regards the whole sentence then yes, the number should come after the punctuation and there should be no space (because there is already space above punctuation). But sometimes writers add notes to individual words in one sentence and in that case it can be necessary to add a hair space if the number melts together with the last letter of the word.

Comment: @Wolff Yes, a hair space or thin space for aesthetic reasons to avoid clashing and make it look like natural spacing – but no space visually.

Comment: ermmm..... why not answers rather than comments?? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already in the comments, but to answer this, I regularly and consistently use thin/hair spaces before footnote numbers, to separate these a bit. Without these thin/hair spaces added, footnotes will generally be too close to the preceding word, sometimes even sticking to it.

Obviously, a full space would be too much, and should always be avoided.

A preview of something I'm just working on ...

[image]

Comment: How do you add this thin space In LaTeX? Maybe somebody knows this off-hand.

Comment: Maybe `\thinspace`?

Comment: @stephanmg probably not a good idea to do this manually go to tex.se and ask there how to do it. In general there is a package for this sort of thing that is very very strictky adhering to some well used convention, that probably can both manage the number positioning of fiitnotes and adding of space